# Can't Center Twitter Follow Button and Some Text Cut Out

Tags: html, css, twitter, twitter-button

I'm getting some peculiar behavior on my twitter follow button. It doesn't seem to center and some text is cut out (text should be 'Follow @HackerUofT' but it only shows 'Follow').
Link http://hacker-universityoftoronto.appspot.com/

```
<center class="social_media">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/HackerUofT" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @HackerUofT</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</center>
```

When I inspect element on Chrome and change the center to a div it seems to fix everything but when I actually edit the code to a div it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use ceneter tag as it will be removed in html5 standarts. Use text-align.
http://jsfiddle.net/6f5aL/

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/HackerUofT" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @HackerUofT</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I replaced all the center tags and used text-align instead but the text is still getting cut out.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Everything looks right in chromium.

Comment: Chrome (19.0.1084.52 m) also. Yeah, seems to work in Mozilla.

Comment: Try to remove your cache (F5 or ctrl+shif+del). I use the same version and it works for me.

Comment: Hm... seems to be still uncentered on my side after clearing the cache. It's also fine on IE lol :P

Comment: This is what I get: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0a673hp7e .I'll look into it a bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got the culprit. When I inspect your code, the `show-screen-name` attribute was set to `false`.

Just add `data-show-screen-name="true"` to your `<a href>` line as shown below.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/HackerUofT" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="true">Follow @HackerUofT</a>
```

Nothing else to change.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align cetner in social media class

```
.social_media
{
    text-align:center
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CsETG/